# Rewrite rules for a domain with folder and bluehost

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, bluehost

I have a domain with bluehost.com and not able to get the rewrite rules working properly. Their support is not helpful!

this is what I need. I have the domain "abc.com" and have the files inside "abc.com/v1" so I need

```
http://abc.com/v1/about-us.php should be written as http://abc.com/v1/about-us
```

Please advise..With my little knowledge I tried this based on reading some examples..but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^abc\.com\v1$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^about-us/(.*) about-us.php/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/about-us)(/.*|)$ /$1.php$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks..will try that. I doubt if i will have access to httpd.conf. Looks like they have enabled it ..will confirm. One question, if we don't mention the /v1 in the rules then in future if I add  folder call v2 and need to write rules, how can i do that? it doesn't matter as this file has to go anyways inside each folder I create?

Comment: Made required edit to take whatever folder name comes before `about-us`. It could be v1, v2 or `any-thing-else`

Comment: I tried this and not working,..may be its not enabled . when i contacted them they said it should be enabled by default. Also, one question - usually when the rules doesn't work, it always show 500 Internal error right? but now after adding the above rules, I see a 404 error

Comment: Which URL did you use for your testing and in which directory did you place above .htaccess?

Comment: It tried putting the above code in both places 1) inside /abc.com and 2)/abc.com/v1 . when I tired the first one, I did not put it in the second one and vice versa. Not able to share the actual domain/url yet for different reasons..sorry.

Comment: Do not want your actual URL. You can hide domain with something like `http://abc.com/v1/foo/bar/bla` I just need to know the structure of URL you tried

Comment: I just corrected a typo. Please try it again. Hope you are using URL: `http://abc.com/v1/about-us` for you testing. **You must use above code in root of `/abc.com`**